# Images is resized on upload to media library (only on production)

Tags: wordpress

I have a strange error in WordPress that I haven't encountered before. By the way this is only happening in production, everything works fine on localhost; so I am guessing this might be a server issue. There is some kind of max file size / width set?

I have a couple of images that are quite big (2000x2100px) and they get resized to 1800 when uploaded to the WordPress Media Library. This is before any thumbnail cropping and image size functions start executing. It also only happens with bigger image and I think its width related.

Any ideas why this might be happening and where to look further?

Answer (score 1):

I would check your list of plugins... perhaps MU plugins or Drop-ins.  Perhaps your host is forcing you to use something that prevents large images from being uploaded?

We use a plugin called [imsanity](https://wordpress.org/plugins/imsanity/) which forces the original images to be resized during upload, and before "crunching", to no more than 2000px wide or tall (option to change that value in it's settings) to prevent users from abusing default "full" size option that can happen.  There is no reason to have an image larger than 2000px wide, for example, from showing on our site.

If you have no plugin like this, then I would check with the host to see if they have something that runs on the server that causes this.  This is obviously something that is running pre-WordPress taking over (again, if there is no plugin).

In most cases, it's a good thing and a lot more people should implement something like this!  In fact, I believe it should be part of WP core.  All it effects is the "full size" image, allowing you to crunch down any size thumbnail you need from that.  The only issue would be if you needed it slightly larger, but looking from a practical point of view, when would you really need to show a 4k pixel image on a site, for example?

Nothing gets me more aggravated then visiting a site to see a 4k, 4MB image loading on my screen... especially if I visit that site on a mobile device!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your **functions.php** file

```
@ini_set( 'upload_max_size' , '64M' );
@ini_set( 'post_max_size', '64M');
@ini_set( 'max_execution_time', '300' );
```

Comment: This is before resizing starts as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Unless you are not experiencing any problems with the upload, only after the upload? For example, are the image files under 2MB? Is it that they are uploading fine, but they're automatically being resized? Is that to the original image or is a copy made? Please elaborate.

Comment: They are under 2MB. They are automatically being resized and the original image is being resized, no copy is made. Upload works fine otherwise.

Comment: Is this happening in general to images you are uploading to the gallery, post, featured image, ... ?

Comment: The issue is in general.

Comment: Also the max height is always 1920px

Comment: Strange. Not my favorite solution, but have you contacted your hosting about it?